# Why was Drew "dejected" after the capture-the-flag game in Divergent?

Tags: divergent

After the capture-the-flag game in Divergent, in which Drew was on the winning team,

> Peter, Molly, and Drew sit across from the members in the corner. Their chests and backs are splattered with blue and pink paint, and they look dejected.

Would Drew *really* be upset because his friends lost and he won?

Answer (score 2):

I re-read that carefully and think it is just an oops. Possibly, he is dejected because Tris and Christina played a key role.